# Why does <h:column><f:facet name="header"><h:outputText> render as th instead of td

Tags: jsf

I have below code:

```
<h:dataTable class="pretty" value="#{ftManagedBean.ftDataModel}" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="Outstanding"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:column>       
</h:dataTable>
```

But it prints Name and Outstanding between `<th></th>` tags. Why? I need them in `<td></td>` tags. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Name and Outstanding end up in `<th>` elements because you placed them inside `<f:facet name="header">` tags.  Remove those and they'll be output to `<td>` tags.

```
<h:dataTable class="pretty" value="#{ftManagedBean.ftDataModel}" >
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="Outstanding"/>
    </h:column>       
</h:dataTable>
```

See the [JSF HTML Tag Reference](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html) for an example on creating a table.

Comment: it only prints <td></td> Name is not there

Comment: @user2153566 Please edit the question to show what you have right now.

Comment: Apparently `ftDataModel` is empty. Perhaps you actually need a `<h:panelGrid>`?

Comment: Based on [OP's follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603773/why-does-this-return-null) it seems that the data model is indeed empty. Well, that's indeed a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code into this:

```
<h:dataTable class="pretty" value="#{ftManagedBean.ftDataModel}" >
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="Outstanding"/>
    </h:column>       
</h:dataTable>
```

If you wrap your output text within the `<f:facet name="header">` this corresponds to `<th>` (table header), otherwise they will be printed in `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

I try this solution and ok. 
(http://www.coderanch.com/t/431222/JSF/java/dynamically-set-panel-header-condition)

```
    <rich:dataGrid value="#{myMB.student.list}" rendered="#{!empty myMB.student and !empty myMB.student.list}" var="st" rowKeyVar="row">
        <rich:panel>                                            
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup id="panelHeader">
                <h:outputText value="Just one student" id="header1" required="true" rendered="#{!myMB.manyStudents}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{row+1}º Student"  id="header2" required="true"  rendered="#{myMB.manyStudents}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>                                 
            </f:facet>
    <rich:panel>
```