# Why does this return null?

Tags: java, hibernate

I sent the date value successfully. I checked from the 'Scoped Variables'.

This is a function in my bean that calls a function in helper:

```
public DataModel getFt() {
    ftDataModel = new ListDataModel((List) fthelper.getByBeginDate(beginDate));
    return ftDataModel;
}
```

This is the function that sent `beginDate` to Hibernate. But here it returns null. Why?

```
public FinancialTransactions getByBeginDate(String beginDate){            
    List<FinancialTransactions> FtList = null;        
    try {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from FinancialTransactions where DATE='" + beginDate + "'");
        FtList = (List<FinancialTransactions>) q.list();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return FtList.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Because the query doesn't find anything?

Comment: maybe no data returned by query, try to run query separately and check how many rows it return

Comment: Is the exception stack trace printed ?

Comment: Side-note: you really should be sanitizing your input. This is open to injection. [See here](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-hibernate).

Comment: @Brian yes, this `where DATE='" + beginDate + "'"` is very tasty :-D

Comment: there is data according to criteria

Comment: when i try to debug i get this error:"No variables to display because there's no current thread"

Answer (score 0):

One from these:

```
org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query q = session.createQuery("from FinancialTransactions where DATE='" + beginDate + "'");
```

throw exception. Use debugger or simple System.out... to find which of those two.

Comment: If that is the case then, exception stack trace would have been printed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters in your query:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from FinancialTransactions where DATE=:date").setParameter("date",beginDate);
```

There should be no inner exception or else FtList.get(0) would result in exception also.

My guess is formating. You use string representation of dates. Always a bad idea since there are many things that can go wrong in convertions.

Comment: i use "." as a seperator. Is that wrong? also i dont know what "FtList.get(0)" means ? is that wrong?

Comment: return FtList.get(0); would throw an exception if the query failed with error because the list (FtList) would be null. Using "." as separator is no problem, but your database might use another format.

Comment: DATE field in db is VARCHAR so i think no problem.

Comment: FtList.get(0); what that mean?

Comment: return FtList.get(0) is the last statement of method getByBeginDate. You should turn on hibernate query logging and check if the statement generated for the query is as expected and returns correct results. It may happen that beginDate has hours/minutes/seconds and the db field does not.